# How to add quotes for strings and null values between commas by using regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace

Maybe its trivial questions but I have problem with it. I have following string:

```
,a1a,1a1,11,,aaa,,,a,84.34,"",ssd
```

I want to achieve following effect by using regex:

```
"","a1a","1a1",11,"","aaa","","","a",84.34,"","ssd"
```

So I want to everything between commas was surrounded quotes, except integers and floating point numbers. How to do this using regex?

Comment: Can you clarify how `s"sd` was converted into `"ssd"`?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov sorry, my mistake, it should be ssd instead s"sd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(*SKIP)(*F) Magic**

In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eM9yR5), have a look at the replacements at the bottom.

This is a great task for `preg_replace`, because PCRE (the regex engine used by PHP) has a beautiful feature to skip certain content.

You can do it in one step with this lovely regex (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eM9yR5)):

```
((?<=^|,)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:(?=,)|$)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=^|,)[^,]*(?:(?=,)|$))
```

**Explanation**

- The outside parentheses capture everything to Group 1.
- There are two parts to the regex, on each side of the `|` OR
- The left side of the alternation  `|` uses `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to match these floats and integers you don't want. We use the lookbehind `(?<=^|,)` to make sure there is a comma behind (or the beginning of the string), and the `(?:(?=,)|$)` to check that what follows is a comma or the end of the string. After matching, we deliberately fail, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string.
- The right side uses `[^,]*` to match anything that is not a comma, including an empty sring, and we know it is the right content because it was not matched by the expression on the left. Again, we use lookarounds to check our position.
- The replacement string `'"\1"'` embeds our match into double quotes.

**How to use it in code:**

```
$regex = "~((?<=^|,)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:(?=,)|$)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=^|,)[^,]*(?:(?=,)|$))~";
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,'"\1"',$string);
```

Comment: For PHP project this solutions is better, becouse it's resistant to invalid floating-point numbers, and special characters. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant:

```
$regex = '/(?<![^,])(?!"[^"]*")(?![-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b)[^,]*+(?![^,])/';
$result = preg_replace($regex, '"$0"', $subject);
```

In somewhat more readable form:

```
(?<![^,])
(?!
  "[^"]*"
  |
  [-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b
)
[^,]*+
(?![^,])
```

The major points of interest are:

- The negative lookbehind `(?<![^,])` to match the leading delimiter (or absence thereof).  You can read it as *if there's a character before this position, it must not be non-comma*.  It isn't always possible to use this idiom, but I like it because it feels less clumsy than the more common `(?<=^|,)`, and it doesn't waste a capturing group like the `(^|,)` idiom.
- The negative lookahead `(?![^,])` similarly acts as the ending anchor.
- In the lookahead to prevent it matching already-quoted fields, I'm assuming I don't have to worry about escaped quotes.  Those are easy enough to deal with, but first you need to know whether it uses backslashes (`"a\"b\"c"`) or quotes (`"a""b""c"`) to escape them.
- The negative lookahead to prevent it matching a number uses a regex from RegexBuddy's library, and it's the loosest of several such regexes.  If you need something more precise, it's available.